# Reactjs - how to pass props to Route?

Tags: reactjs

I’m learning React Navigation using React-Router-Dom. I have created a simple app to illustrate the problem:

Inside App.js I have a Route, that points to the url “/” and loads the functional Component DataSource.js.

Inside DataSource.js I have a state with the variable name:”John”. There is also a buttonwith the onclick pointing to a class method that’s supposed to load a stateless component named ShowData.js using Route.

ShowData.js receives props.name.

What I want to do is: when the button in DataSource.js is clicked, the url changes to “/showdata”, the ShowData.js is loaded and displays the props.name received by DataSource.js, and DataSource.js goes away.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import DataSource from './containers/DataSource'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Route path='/' component={DataSource}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

DataSource.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ShowData from '../components/ShowData'
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom'
class DataSource extends Component{
    state={
        name:' John',
    }

    showDataHandler = ()=>{
        <Route path='/showdata' render={()=><ShowData name={this.state.name}/>}/>
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                 <button onClick={this.showDataHandler}>Go!</button>                
            </div>           
        )
    }
}

export default DataSource;
```

ShowData.js

```
import React from 'react';

const showData = props =>{
    return (
        <div>            
            <p>{props.name}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default showData;
```

I have tried the following, but, even though the url does change to '/showdata', the DataSource component is the only thing being rendered to the screen:

DataSource.js

```
showDataHandler = ()=>{
        this.props.history.push('/showdata')
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                 <button onClick={this.showDataHandler}>Go!</button>    
                 <Route path='/showdata' render={()=>{<ShowData name={this.state.name}/>}}/>     
            </div>           
        )
    }
```

I also tried the following but nothing changes when the button is clicked:

DataSource.js

```
 showDataHandler = ()=>{
        <Route path='/showdata' render={()=>{<ShowData name={this.state.name}/>}}/>
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                 <button onClick={this.showDataHandler}>Go!</button> 
            </div>           
        )
    }
```

How can I use a nested Route inside DataSource.js to pass a prop to another component?

Thanks.

EDIT: As user Sadequs Haque so kindly pointed out, it is possible to retrieve the props when you pass that prop through the url, like '/showdata/John', but that's not what I'd like to do: I'd like that the url was just '/showdata/'.

He also points out that it is possible to render either DataSource or ShowData conditionally, but that will not change the url from '/' to '/showdata'.

Comment: "How can I use a nested Route inside DataSource.js to pass a prop to another component?"
The easiest way to do that would be to use Router props. So instead of creating a new router in the nested component, you would just link to the main router and pass a prop through the main router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. At least, one way of doing it, anyway.

First, I added a route to the ShowData component inside App.js, so that ShowData could get access to the router props. I also included exact to DataSource route, so it wouldn't be displayed when ShowData is rendered.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import DataSource from './containers/DataSource'
import ShowData from './components/ShowData'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <Route exact path='/' component={DataSource}/>
      {/* 1. add Route to ShowData */}
      <Route path='/showdata' component={ShowData}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Inside DataSource, I modified the showDataHandler method to push the url I wanted, AND added a query param to it.

DataSource.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DataSource extends Component{
    state={
        name:' John',
    }

    showDataHandler = ()=>{
        this.props.history.push({
          pathname:'/showdata',
          query:this.state.name
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                 <button onClick={this.showDataHandler}>Go!</button>                
            </div>           
        )
    }
}

export default DataSource;
```

And, finally, I modified ShowData to be a Class, so I could use state and have access to ComponentDidMount (I guess is also possible to use hooks here, if you don't want to change it to a Class).

Inside ComponentDidMount, I get the query param and update the state.

ShowData.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ShowData extends Component{

  state={
    name:null
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({name:this.props.location.query})
  }

  render(){
    
    return (
      <div>            
          <p>{this.state.name}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }    
}

export default ShowData;
```

Now, when I click the button, the url changes to '/showdata' (and only '/showdata') and the prop name is displayed.

Hope this helps someone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple issues to solve and this solution worked as you wanted.

`App.js` should have all the routes. I used Route params to pass the props to ShowData. So, `/showdata/value` would pass `value` as params to `ShowData` and render `ShowData`. And then wrapped the Routes with BrowserRouter. And then used exact route to point `/` to DataSource because otherwise DataSource would still get rendered as `/showdata/:name` has `/`

`DataSource.js` will simply `Link` the button to the appropriate `Route`. You would populate `DataSourceValue` with the appropriate value.

`ShowData.js` would read and display value from the router prop. I figured out the object structure of the router params from a console.log() of the props object. It ended up being `props.match.params`

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import DataSource from "./DataSource";
import ShowData from "./ShowData";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={DataSource} />
        <Route path="/showdata/:name" component={ShowData} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**DataSource.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ShowData from "./ShowData";
class DataSource extends Component {
  state = {
    name: " John",
    clicked: false
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.clicked)
      return (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ name: "John", clicked: true });
            console.log(this.state.clicked);
          }}
        >
          Go!
        </button>
      );
    else {
      return <ShowData name={this.state.name} />;
    }
  }
}

export default DataSource;
```

**ShowData.js**

```
import React from "react";

const ShowData = (props) => {
  console.log(props);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShowData;
```

Here is my scripts on CodeSandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-hodgkin-yfjs6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. The ShowData component is not loaded, nor the url changes.

Comment: Give me 10 minutes, let me get an IDE running.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I understand what you did, and I could pass the name John by, instead of using the url "/showdata/value" like you did, by concatenating "/showdata/"+this.state.name and then retrieving it with props.match.params.name as you did. The problem is I just want to pass the props to the ShowData component without including it in the url. The url should be only '/showdata/'. But thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You can return(<ShowData name={variableName}/> directly in DataSource

Comment: How do I do it, please?

Comment: @EiteWald Updated the answer. Check Sandbox.

Comment: Again, I understand what you did, but the problem is the url is not changing to '/showdata/. That's the question: how to pass props to component AND change the url without including the props in the url. But thank you very much fro trying. I mean it. Thanks.